# How to change axis foreground?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

How to change x and y axis's black text color?
I have tried changing every black color in every xaml file in *WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization* namespace.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Ctrl+Shift in the sample app - you'll see the `TextBlock` is inside of a `NumericAxisLabel` and when you search the code - you can see that it's created by `NumericAxis.CreateAxisLabel()`. One of its base classes - `DisplayAxis` has a `AxisLabelStyle` property you can use to apply a style to that label, so if you set that in your chart - you can use a style that specifies a setter for the `Foreground` property with a different brush.

Comment: Thanks. Really helped but it only changed foregrounds of y-axis and not for x-axis. How do I change x-axis also?

Comment: Can you post your XAML?

Comment: Thanks but I finally solved it by setting IndependentAxis of the series to a CategoryAxis along with setting custom styles. Lots of head scratching.